# Python's property decorator does not work as expected

Tags: python, class, properties, decorator, new-style-class

```
class Silly:
    @property
    def silly(self):
        "This is a silly property"
        print("You are getting silly")
        return self._silly

    @silly.setter
    def silly(self, value):
        print("You are making silly {}".format(value))
        self._silly = value

    @silly.deleter
    def silly(self):
        print("Whoah, you killed silly!")
        del self._silly

s = Silly()
s.silly = "funny"
value = s.silly
del s.silly
```

But it does not print "You are getting silly", "You are making silly funny",... as expected. Don't know why. Can you have me figure out, folks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The `property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) only works with [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867)). Make `Silly` extend from `object` explicitly to make it a new-style class. (In Python 3, all classes are new-style classes)

```
class Silly(object):
    @property
    def silly(self):
        # ...
    # ...
```

Comment: class Silly --> class Silly(object), and it worked. I missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you most likely are aware of the correct method to add properties would be to use:

```
@property
def silly(self):
    return self._silly


@silly.setter:
def silly(self, value):
    self._silly = value
```

But this requires new style classes, that is that somewhere in the chain  there is supposed to be a `class ParentClass(object):`. The similar option of using `silly = property(get_silly, set_silly)` has the same requirement.

However, there is another option, and that is to use a corresponding private variable, like `self._silly`, and override the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` methods:

```
def __getattr__(self, name): 
    """Called _after_ looking in the normal places for name."""  

    if name == 'silly':
        self._silly
    else:
        raise AttributeError(name)


def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    """Called _before_ looking in the normal places for name."""
    if name == 'silly':
        self.__dict__['_silly'] = value
    else:
        self.__dict__[name] = value
```

Notice how `__getattr__` will be called *after* checking for other attributes, but that `__setattr__` is called *before* checking for other attributes. Therefore the former can and should raise an error if not an accepted attribute, and the latter should set the attribute. Do *not* use `self._silly = value` within `__setattr__` as that would cause infinite recursion.

Also note that since we're dealing with old style classes here, you should actually use the dict method, and not the newer `baseclass.__setattr__(self, attr, value)`, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). A similar `__delattr__()` does also exist, if you want it.

Using this code, you can now do stuff like:

```
i_am = Silly()
i_am.silly = 'No, I'm clever'
print i_am.silly
```